# Python and Django basics

Tags: python, django

I am a Java developer and am going to try out Python/Django for the first time and I had some basic questions from my end.

Which are the go-to python forums?
Which are the go-to django forums?
What are the go-to IDEs? (I use Eclipse for Java)
Are there any books you encourage or discourage me from reading?
Any final words on my conversion to the dark side of dynamic programming?

I do realize that I can just Google this stuff but then i wouldn't be getting the experts feedback on what is good or not, so thanks ahead of time.

K

Comment: This question is completely subjective, as will be most answers. Dive into Python is the standard Python tutorial, and Django has its own introduction. 

You can write Python in basically any IDE. (Java programmers tend to need IDE help to deal with the mounds of useless code, which Python does not have.) I use emacs.

Comment: And why is Python "the dark side"?! Surely that's Java... =p

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: The dark side meaning that there's no turning back cause it's dangerous and awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.djangoproject.com/community/

http://www.python.org/community/lists/

All (user) mailing lists are extremely friendly, just make sure not to ask user questions on any of the dev-lists.

"Welcome",
Klaas

Answer (score 1):

Phenomenal book on python(and it's free) http://diveintopython.net/

Other than that, the Django forum is awesome and http://djangobook.com is great too.

Have fun, and good luck. Once you go Dynamic you never go... (I have nothing that rhymes with dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

The best resource in my opinion is right here a Stackoverflow.  I haven't found any good python or django books that were better than just doing it yourself. If you know how to program, jump right in.  Start making a django app.  You'll find it pretty straightforward.

I prefer vim but a lot of people use Eclipse or Komodo.